# Split comma separated string in array without nested for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this particular situation where I have an array of objects where one of the object element is comma separated string. How can I separate it without using nested for loop?

Array I have :

```
[{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '9999999999,4455332244,7766554433',
    id: 3,
},
{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '1111111111,2222222222,4444444444',
    id: 4,
}]
```

Array I want from above :

```
[ 
  { number: '9999999999', type: 'type1', id: 3 },
  { number: '4455332244', type: 'type1', id: 3 },
  { number: '7766554433', type: 'type1', id: 3 },
  { number: '1111111111', type: 'type1', id: 4 },
  { number: '2222222222', type: 'type1', id: 4 },
  { number: '4444444444', type: 'type1', id: 4 } ]
```

Comment: have you tried anything? why no nested loop?

Comment: I have tried and all I can think is nested for loop. Can we do it without nested for loop?

Comment: you could do this with two .map calls https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: No, you can't, unless stuff like newer _loops_ called `map()` and `reduce()` won't be considered a _loop_, though technically they are.

Answer (score 2):

you could use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) , for each `details` item, split with `,` and use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the array to the structure you want then [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add it to the end result :

```js
const data = [{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '9999999999,4455332244,7766554433',
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    type: 'type1',
    details: '1111111111,2222222222,4444444444',
    id: 4,
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((all, {type, details, id}) => {
  return all.concat(details.split(',').map(e => ({
      type: type,
      id: id,
      number: e
    })
  ))
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

( see also [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

Answer (score 2):

> How can I separate it without using nested for loop?

You can't. However you only need two loops:

```
const result = [];

for(const {type, details, id} of input)
  for(const number of details.split("."))
     result.push({ number, type, id });
```

Comment: OP says _"How can I separate it without using nested for loop?"_

Comment: Already made that comment under the question, though _the other_ don't use `for` :)

Comment: @LGSon but they rely on methods that will probably iterate the data mor often, therefore counting as loops

Comment: Yes, I ironically meant the _word_ `for` though :) ... totally agree with you, and wrote this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168295/split-comma-separated-string-in-array-without-nested-for-loop-in-javascript#comment89319974_51168295 ... and an upvote

Answer (score 0):

You could map the inner splitted values for new objects.

```js
var data = [{ type: 'type1', details: '9999999999,4455332244,7766554433', id: 3 }, { type: 'type1', details: '1111111111,2222222222,4444444444', id: 4 }],
    result = [].concat(
        ...data.map(
            ({ type, details, id }) => details.split(',').map(
                number => ({ number, type, id })
            )
        )
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

An `Array.prototype.reduce` would be of a great help here:

```
const data = [{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '9999999999,4455332244,7766554433',
    id: 3,
},
{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '1111111111,2222222222,4444444444',
    id: 4,
}]

const result = data.reduce((all, { type, id, details }) => {
    details.split(',').forEach(number => all.push({number, type, id}));
    return all;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.reduce()` to get that output:

```js
var arr = [{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '9999999999,4455332244,7766554433',
    id: 3,
},
{
    type: 'type1',
    details: '1111111111,2222222222,4444444444',
    id: 4,
}];

var res = arr.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  obj.details.split(',').forEach((item) => {
    var tempObj = {};
    tempObj.number = item;
    tempObj.type = obj.type;
    tempObj.id = obj.id;
    acc.push(tempObj);
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is already several `reduce` answers, and one also use `forEach` ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51168466/2827823 ... posted about 15 min before yours, so why yet one more??

Answer (score -1):

```
     const test = [{
                type: 'type1',
                details: '9999999999,4455332244,7766554433',
                id: 3,
            },
            {
                type: 'type1',
                details: '1111111111,2222222222,4444444444',
                id: 4,
            }]
     const ans = test.map(ele=>ele.details.split(',')
                     .map(el=> ({number : el, type: ele.type,id : ele.id})))
                     .reduce((a,b)=>a.concat(b));

console.log(ans);
```